# How to access to data from previous emission in rx?

Tags: java, rx-java

The question is about `rx` programming. I have a code:

```
Observable.from(array)
          .map(array_item1 -> array_item2)
          .map(array_item3 -> array_item4)
          .map(array_item5 -> array_item6)
```

and in the third `map` call I need access not only `array_item5` but also `array_item1` or `array_item3`.
it should seem like this:

```
...    
.map(array_item5 -> array_item5 + array_item1)
...
```

Is there any special pattern or an operator for this?

Comment: Maybe simple do `Observable.from(array).toList().map(array -> //access full array})`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want access previous emissions, you need save them somewhere. There is accumulator operators:

**Collect** - collects all emissions in single mutable structure

```
Observable.from(Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6))
      .collect(ArrayList::new,
        (array, item) -> {
            //access previous and current emissions
            array.add(item);
        })
```

**Scan** - in addition to collect, it returns all previous emissions on **every** next:

```
Observable.from(Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6))
    .scan(new ArrayList<>(), (array, item) -> {
           array.add(item)     
           return array;
          })
    .map(collectedItems -> {
          //access all previous and curent emissions on every new
          return collectedItems;
        })
```